# How to set Altair graph to specific increments?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, altair

So I'm working with data from a survey I created. I am trying to create a stacked bar chart that shows the difference in gender vs depression from the responses I received. The values for depression were 1,2,3,4,5 nothing in-between. When I try to plot this, its giving me incremental values up to 5. How can I just have the graph plot 1 - 5 without the increment values?

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
x='Depression',
y='Responses',
color='Gender',
order=alt.Order(
  'Gender',
  sort='ascending'
)
```

Which gives me this: 
[image]

To be fair, I know this isn't the only thing wrong with my chart, but I'm trying to figure out how to make this actually work. This being only one of the issues I'm running into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the *ordinal* data type in your encoding.

Numerical data in altair defaults to a *quantitative* encoding type, which is suitable for continuous, real-valued data. An *ordinal* encoding is suitable for discrete ordered categories like those in your data.

You can specify an ordinal encoding using the `"*:O"` shorthand in your encodings:

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
  x='Depression:O',
  y='Responses',
  color='Gender',
  order=alt.Order(
    'Gender',
    sort='ascending'
  )
)
```

For more information, see [Encoding Data Types](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/encoding.html#encoding-data-types) in the Altair documentation, and in particular the [Effect of Data Type on Axis Scales](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/encoding.html#effect-of-data-type-on-axis-scales) section.